# Displaying content in asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started using asp.net and have build a webpage which is used to provide request data to a web service and displaying the response . I have created few text box's which accept the data from user for sending the request and I am displaying the response using label's and images tag . All of these elements are on the same page .

Issue: I want the labels and images tag to be displayed after the response is received from the web service and does not want them to be displayed on page when the user is requesting to the web service. Currently all of the elements are displayed on the page .

Please provide suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Panel or Placeholder controls could be of help : you can group controls into them and display it on will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a separate page to display the response, or set `Visible` to false (perhaps on a containing panel) when there is no response.